# How to get data from multiple tables of MySQL DB and manuplate it using PHP to display graphs?

Tags: php, mysql, graph, highcharts

I want to make graph for yearly report of sales, purchases and transfers. MySQL quires and PHP codes and Graph codes are below.

**MySQL Quires**

> SALES QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS sales, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM sales 

WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC
```

> PURCHASES QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS num, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM purchases 

WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC
```

> TRANSFERS QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS num, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM transfers 

WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC
```

Now, the sales query returned following data

```
sales, dataofmonth
1   2015-December
3   2015-January
```

There are only data of January and December available in database. So, I want to display 0 for other months.

**CHART / GRAPH**

I'm using high-charts to display graph page using following code which works perfect but I'm unable to make it dynamic with PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();

        var example = 'line-basic', 
        theme = 'default';

        (function($){ // encapsulate jQuery


            $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Report',
            x: -20 //center
        },/*
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },*/
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '<?=$_SESSION['mcs_name']?>'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },/*
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },*/
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Purchases',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales',
            data: [<?=@$janS?>, <?=@$febS?>, <?=@$marS?>, <?=@$aprS?>, <?=@$mayS?>, <?=@$junS?>, <?=@$julS?>, <?=@$augS?>, <?=@$sepS?>, <?=@$octS?>, <?=@$novS?>, <?=@$decS?>]
        }, {
            name: 'Transfers',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }]
    });
});

        })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**PHP CODE**

My PHP code have a lot of issues as I'm beginner in creating graphs.

```
<?php
    $purchases = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS num, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM purchases WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC");
    $sales = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS num, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM sales WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC");
    $transfers = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS num, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%M' ) AS dataofmonth FROM transfers WHERE `date` LIKE '2015%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') ASC");

    while($objP = $purchases->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-January")
            $janP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-February")
            $febP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-March")
            $marP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-April")
            $aprP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-May")
            $mayP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-June")
            $junP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-July")
            $julP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-August")
            $augP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-September")
            $sepP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-October")
            $octP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-November")
            $novP = $objP->num;
        if($objP->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-December")
            $decP = $objP->num;
    }
    while($objS = $sales->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-January")
            $janS = $objS->num;
        else
            $janS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-February")
            $febS = $objS->num;
        else
            $febS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-March")
            $marS = $objS->num;
        else
            $marS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-April")
            $aprS = $objS->num;
        else
            $aprS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-May")
            $mayS = $objS->num;
        else
            $mayS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-June")
            $junS = $objS->num;
        else
            $junS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-July")
            $julS = $objS->num;
        else
            $julS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-August")
            $augS = $objS->num;
        else
            $augS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-September")
            $sepS = $objS->num;
        else
            $sepS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-October")
            $octS = $objS->num;
        else
            $octS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-November")
            $novS = $objS->num;
        else
            $novS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-December")
            $decS = $objS->num;
        else
            $decS = 0;

    }
    while($objT = $transfers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-January")
            $janT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-February")
            $febT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-March")
            $marT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-April")
            $aprT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-May")
            $mayT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-June")
            $junT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-July")
            $julT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-August")
            $augT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-September")
            $sepT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-October")
            $octT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-November")
            $novT = $objT->num;
        if($objT->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-December")
            $decT = $objT->num;
    }
?>
```

In above php code I was trying to put data into follow line of high chart codes but failed.

```
{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [<?=@$janS?>, <?=@$febS?>, <?=@$marS?>, <?=@$aprS?>, <?=@$mayS?>, <?=@$junS?>, <?=@$julS?>, <?=@$augS?>, <?=@$sepS?>, <?=@$octS?>, <?=@$novS?>, <?=@$decS?>]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your goal and workflow correct you should replace :

```
 while($objS = $sales->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-January")
            $janS = $objS->num;
        else
            $janS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-February")
            $febS = $objS->num;
        else
            $febS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-March")
            $marS = $objS->num;
        else
            $marS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-April")
            $aprS = $objS->num;
        else
            $aprS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-May")
            $mayS = $objS->num;
        else
            $mayS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-June")
            $junS = $objS->num;
        else
            $junS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-July")
            $julS = $objS->num;
        else
            $julS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-August")
            $augS = $objS->num;
        else
            $augS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-September")
            $sepS = $objS->num;
        else
            $sepS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-October")
            $octS = $objS->num;
        else
            $octS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-November")
            $novS = $objS->num;
        else
            $novS = 0;

        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-December")
            $decS = $objS->num;
        else
            $decS = 0;

    }
```

to :

```
$salesArr = array_fill(1,12,0);
 while($objS = $sales->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-January")
            $salesArr[1] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-February")
            $salesArr[2] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-March")
            $salesArr[3] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-April")
            $salesArr[4] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-May")
            $salesArr[5] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-June")
            $salesArr[6] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-July")
            $salesArr[7] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-August")
            $salesArr[8] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-September")
            $salesArr[9] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-October")
            $salesArr[10] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-November")
            $salesArr[11] = $objS->num;
        if($objS->dataofmonth == "".date('Y')."-December")
            $salesArr[12] = $objS->num;

    }
```

and change your:

```
{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [<?=@$janS?>, <?=@$febS?>, <?=@$marS?>, <?=@$aprS?>, <?=@$mayS?>, <?=@$junS?>, <?=@$julS?>, <?=@$augS?>, <?=@$sepS?>, <?=@$octS?>, <?=@$novS?>, <?=@$decS?>]
}
```

to:

```
{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [<?=implode(',',$salesArr) ?>]
}
```

I hope my guess is correct and helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks for your great response. `array_fill` is great. I don't know what is the issue with array it still return only 2 values and does not return 0. I just use after while loop `print_r($satesArr);` and it return ` Array ( [1] => 3 [12] => 1 ) ` only.

Comment: If I use after while loop `var_dump($satesArr);` it return `array (size=2)
  1 => int 3
  12 => int 1`

Comment: just show me your current php code...ooohhhh no... I have typos, check edited answer. that must be `$salesArr` everywhere :-)

Comment: Thank it works for me now ;) Sorry I'm unable to voteup your answer because of reputation is under 15